# React-Router 1.0 - 100% Client Side Routing - Page Refresh causes 404 error

Tags: react-router

I am creating a website for a client that will use strictly client side react-routing script.

Here is a sample of the router ....

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { generateRoute } from '../utils/localized-routes';

export default (
  <Route component={ require('../components/APP') }>
    { generateRoute({
      paths: ['/', 'audience'],
      component: require('../components/Audience')
    }) }
    { generateRoute({
      paths: ['speaker'],
      component: require('../components/Speaker')
    }) }
    { generateRoute({
      paths: ['board'],
      component: require('../components/Board')
    }) },
    { generateRoute({
      paths: ['questions'],
      component: require('../components/parts/AskQuestion')
    }) }
    <Route path="*" component={ require('../pages/NotFound') } />
  </Route>
);
```

With this being the code for generateRoute:

```
export function generateRoute({ paths, component }) {
  return paths.map(function(path) {
    const props = { key: path, path, component };
    // Static `onEnter` is defined on
    // component, we should pass it to route props
    if (component.onEnter) props.onEnter = component.onEnter;
    return <Route {...props} />;
  });
}
```

**Problem:**

While I understand the Links will bypass server navigation and utilize transition to (client side), on page refresh, I get a "Page Cannot Be found".

1. If I manually put a hash tag before the browser's url input (myexample.com/#speaker), the page appears, but of course I cannot expect the user to do that.
2. If I  must use hash tags to allow client side routing, where do I put them? I put them in the  and/or the router, neither work.
3. Alternatively, can I achieve total client side routing w/o the ugly hash tags? If, so, how do I do it?

I'd much prefer a solution based on #3, but if all else fails I'll take a solution based on #2.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only find a solution using step #2 above and am stuck with hashtags.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from 'react-router';
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createHashHistory'; <-- using this
//  import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';


const routerProps = {
  routes: require('./router/routes'),
  history: createHistory({            <--- added this to remove ugly querystring
    queryKey: false
  }),
  createElement: (component, props) => {
    return React.createElement(component, { ...props });
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Router, { ...routerProps }),
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

**Would still like to know how I can remove the hashtags completely with client-side routing.**